# check session registered in php, than jquery ajax to print session variables

Tags: php, jquery

register session php (in a different file it gets processed):

```
 $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $cust_email; //register session
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //redirect to refering page
 exit;
```

this session value appears in a div on top of every page:

```
 <div class="message">
    <?php
    echo "$message";
    ?>  
 </div>
```

I am trying that this data to be passed to jquery-ajax so that once registered, session variable appears asynchronously in that div. Right now I need to refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just create a php script that gets the session variable you need and echo it if its not empty (your logic).

then you want to use that jquery script to update the div:

```
function loadLog(){
$.ajax({
url: "getsession.php",  
cache: false,  
success: function(html){    
$(".message").html(html);
}});}
```